# Why is it that my CPU goes 100% when syncing music/photos to iPad?

Tags: ipad, itunes, ios, data-synchronization

I wipe my iPad quite often since I'm an iOS developer, but what I'm wondering is that why does my CPU goes 100%? Isn't it quite the same as copying music/photo to a USB drive (which doesn't make my CPU 100%?).

Granted I ticked the "convert to 128 kbps AAC" option, but for photos, I thought they'd only have to resize the photos when syncing?

Comment: What is the Operating System?

Comment: Snow Leopard, latest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"128 kbps AAC" - tells the system to convert audio to AAC encoded files at a quality of 128kbps so this conversion is what is taking the CPU.

AAC is only for audio/video and nothing to do with still images

Comment: Yeah, but it still doesn't explain why I get 100% CPU when syncing music and photos

Comment: It will do this for music - for photos that would be another setting

Answer (score 3):

Resizing the photo's is also CPU intensive operation.

Apple could potentially speed it up by using the GPU for resizing the images, but iTunes must be compatible with old Windows PC's. So I wouldn't hold my breath.